# Scala, Problem with Scala 2.8.1 installation on Maverick

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, ubuntu-10.10, sbaz

i've izpack installer Scala 2.8.1 after install it at /usr/local/scala and set environment variable at etc/environment it's work normally for execute command like scala or scalac, but if i execute sbaz with sudo, the error message show like

```
sudo: sbaz: command not found
```

So i try to execute **sbaz-setup new_sbaz_directory** without sudo, but after i tried to execute command like

```
sbaz install sbt
```

Again the error show like

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/scala/meta/.lock (Permission denied)
```

Why the sbaz not pointing to my sbaz_directory after execute sbaz-setup command ? Is there any solution for my problem ? Thank you

Comment: Maybe installation using sudo or as a normal user can make a difference - thus you can try the other variant, if you haven't tried both already.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the cause of the problem, likely a JVM or Scala crash which left a .lock file.

You can get sbaz to work again by changing the permissions on the .lock file, which will then be deleted when sbaz will run anew :

```
    sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/scala/meta/.lock
```

then :

```
    sbaz install sbt
```

Allowing 777 permission on the file looks scary, but I didn't find any other way to delete the .lock file than by letting sbaz run and delete it by itself...